# using custom css rules while surfing websites

Tags: css

Everyday I visit some websites regularly. Some of them have great content but terrible design. So is there a way to use custom css rules for that ones, without changing every time in Firebug?
For example, I want use line-height:1.5 for a blog to read easily and save that rule for the next time.

Comment: Yes, this is a feature built into some browsers (user CSS) or you can use something like the Greasemonkey extension. Either way, though, this should be asked over on SuperUser or StackOverflow instead as it's not really a UX question.

Comment: Hi Ozan. DA01 is right, this isn't a User Experience issue you're having, it's a question for Firebug forums or some such place. I'll see if any other SE sites are happy to accept this question, and if so we'll migrate it over for you so there's no need to repost this question elsewhere for now.

Comment: Actually, this has already been asked (in more detail) over on SuperUser - http://superuser.com/questions/389813/browser-where-i-can-add-my-own-custom-css-or-javascript

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every (newer) browser there is always the option of using custom CSS. In chrome there is even an extension called [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en), which let you use different custom CSS on different sites:

> Stylebot allows you to quickly manipulate the appearance of any website (using custom CSS).
>
> You pick an element and choose any changes you want to make from the editor. You can change the font size, color, margins, visibility and a lot more. The advanced users can also write the CSS manually.
>
> Using Stylebot, you can personalize the look and feel of your favorite websites. It is also a great tool to learn CSS and for debugging your own site's design.

Comment: I just read that text before I post the question. I thought that it was a plugin like Firebug. I misunderstood. Sorry. Thank you.

Comment: @OzanTuzel No worries :-)